# Split-Path with non standard key names

Tags: powershell, registry

How does one deal with paths like this
**HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\MozillaPlugins\@microsoft.com/GENUINE**
when using `Split-Path`? That forward slash near the end gets treated just like a backslash so **GENUINE** is treated as a separate key, rather than **@microsoft.com/GENUINE** being the key. 
Perhaps a better question is, how does one use `Get-ItemProperty` in this case? I have always used `Split-Path` to separate the Key from the Property in a path like **HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Key\Property** but that fails here. My hope is to be able to provide a single string that I can split up in code, and support older versions of PowerShell as well.
I know the brute force approach would be to just look for the last instance of backslash, and everything to the left is the key, and to the right is the property, but I wonder if there is a more elegant option. Or, something I am missing that would make that approach not even work?

***EDIT:***
So, to verify, I CAN get this to work

```
$path = 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\MozillaPlugins\@microsoft.com/GENUINE\GeckoVersion'
$location = $path.LastIndexOf('\')
$key = $path.Substring(0,$location)
$property = $path.Substring($location+1)
$currentValue = (Get-ItemProperty -path:$key -name:$property).$property
Write-Host "$key "
Write-Host "$property"
Write-Host "$currentValue"
```

But, one it seems like `Split-Path` should handle this better (the path IS a valid path, after all). And two, I'm not sure brute forcing on the last instance of \ doesn't have some hidden down side.

***EDIT:*** I am considering using the following approach to keep the XML simple (i.e. a single node) while also allowing specification of Key or Property, as well as backward compatibility with a simple path. So...
This is what I had before

```
<Rule>[node] regPropertyExists:"HKLM\SOFTWARE\MozillaPlugins\@microsoft.com/GENUINE\GeckoVersion" -eq True</Rule>
```

And this is what I am doing for a Property specific path

```
<Rule>[node] regPropertyExists:"HKLM\SOFTWARE\MozillaPlugins\@microsoft.com/GENUINE P:GeckoVersion" -eq True</Rule>
```

As long as no one has `P:`with a space in front as part of a key or property name I'm good. And THAT seems like an edge case I can live with.
I am also supporting Key specific paths like this

```
<Rule>[node] regKeyExists:"K:HKLM\SOFTWARE\MozillaPlugins\@microsoft.com/GENUINE" -eq True</Rule>
```

And this is a backwards compatible path

```
<Rule>[node] regPropertyExists:"HKLM\SOFTWARE\Px Tasks\Delete_Ex\Test" -eq True</Rule>
```

where the code tests for both a key and a property being found, and if I can't resolve to a single item I throw an error.

Anyone see any gotchas in that approach?

Comment: `get-itemproperty HKLM:\SOFTWARE\MozillaPlugins\@adobe.com/FlashPlayer` works for me just fine. What part of the path are you trying to return exactly? If you want the parent path I would just use: `(gi HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Adobe).PSParentPath` or the leaf with `(get-item HKLM:\SOFTWARE\MozillaPlugins\@adobe.com/FlashPlayer).PSChildName`

Comment: The idea is to start from **HKLM\SOFTWARE\MozillaPlugins\@microsoft.com/GENUINE\GeckoVersion** and be able to get the actual value of the GeckoVersion property.  So I need to first split it into **HKLM\SOFTWARE\MozillaPlugins\@microsoft.com/GENUINE** & **GeckoVersion**, and even using `$key = (Get-Item $path).PSParentPath` where `$path = 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\MozillaPlugins\@microsoft.com/GENUINE\GeckoVersion'` doesn't work on my end. Running PS 5.0.

Comment: Hmm. OK. Not sure off the top of my head then since I'm not used to seeing reg paths like that since its not "real". PSv5: using `$path = "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\MozillaPlugins\@microsoft.com/GENUINE\GeckoVersion"` then I can do `Get-ItemPropertyValue -Path (split-path $path) -Name (Split-Path -leaf $path)` Does that work for you?

Comment: Interesting. It seems that `Get-ItemPropertyValue` works. I'll need to look a bit closer to see why my other code wasn't working. But I feat my main issue will be needing to support PS 2.0. More testing to do.

Comment: Be aware that Split-Path will not handle this the way that you want it to and was never intended to. Split-Path is written to handle both MS and *nix paths so it will always (properly) see the / as a valid path seperator. You will have to get this one on your own. If I get a chance I'll see if I can mock up the situation and write a parser.

Comment: `Get-ItemProperty` would still work easy. `Get-ItemProperty -Path (split-path $path) | select -ExpandProperty (Split-Path -leaf $path)`

Comment: @EBGreen The risk here would be if the property also contained slashes since that is allowed. A dedicated parser would be needed in that case to determine edge cases.

Comment: So, oddly `Write-Host "$(split-path $path -parent)"` is actually returning **HKLM:\SOFTWARE\MozillaPlugins\@microsoft.com\GENUINE** rather than **HKLM:\SOFTWARE\MozillaPlugins\@microsoft.com/GENUINE** but `(Get-ItemProperty -Path:(split-path $path -parent) -Name:(Split-Path $path -leaf)).(Split-Path $path -leaf)` is returning the value correctly, just like `Get-ItemPropertyValue -Path:(split-path $path -parent) -Name:(Split-Path $path -leaf)` is.

Comment: Matt, that's what seems so odd to me, that a key name or a property name are allowed to have slashes, but Split-Path assumes slashes can only be key or property delimiters. It makes Split-Path perfectly useful, right up until it isn't, which is in my mind a rather insidious bug, not a feature. ;)

Comment: I don't know about bug or not, but I believe the issue is in the fact that the registry looks like a file system (and did long before powershell cam along) but doesn't follow the rules of a file system. Then powershell came along and made a best effort attempt to treat it like a file system even though it clearly isn't.

Comment: @EBGreen I suspect it's not a stretch to just say that the Registry is a bug. ;)

Comment: So if I understand, the issue is just wanting to be able to express the path to the key and the property name all in one string? If that is the case then I would say that the expectation is the issue. The Name-Value pairs that are in the registry are actually ***properties*** of the key. I understand that the naming conventions in the registry make it difficult to have a single string that can be parsed to use in Get-ItemProperty, but the fact that you put that string together in the first place means that you already know the actual path and the actual prperty name.

Comment: So, in this scenario, how exactly is $path created? Is it something that you type into your script?

Comment: @EBGreen I am working on a Rules system for a utility, where all the data is in XML. So a rule might look like this `<Rule>[node] regPropertyExists:"HKLM\SOFTWARE\MozillaPlugins\@microsoft.com/GENUINE\GeckoVersion" -eq True</Rule>` and I extract the path from that. there are plenty of rules that are much simpler, and I want to keep things consistent because at least in the short term the XML needs to be human readable/editable. So

Comment: Then it sounds like you have a dilemma. The registry allows for property names that have path delimiters in their names. If you control the Rules then I would whange them to something like this: `<Rule RegPropertyExists:"GeckoVersion" Path:"HKLM\SOFTWARE\MozillaPlugins\@microsoft.com/GENUINE">True</Rule>` Or whatever structure that you want. Regardless your rule will need to distinguish between the path and the property.

Comment: @EBGreen Indeed, a bit of a quandary. If I already had a GUI written I would just revise the XML. But I don't, and many of my users are not coders, they are building Architects. But I may just accept that the Rules stuff is for Power Users and run with added complexity, but with the data done right to start with. I don't want to start one way for convenience, then change it later for correctness. ;)