# Strange Get-Item behaviour

Tags: powershell, registry

If I simply do

```
Get-Item "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\MozillaPlugins\@microsoft.com/GENUINE"
```

I get this on the console

```
NAME
----
@microsoft.com/GENUINE
```

However, this

```
$test = Get-Item "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\MozillaPlugins\@microsoft.com/GENUINE"
Write-Host "$($test.name)"
```

returns the full path, not just the name of the key.

Is this a bug? Intended behavior? Me doing something incorrectly?

Comment: PowerShell has formatting files containing configuration about how certain objects are outputted. Is is why you see default properties and not all properties on objects. Think `GCI C:\temp` for example. You changed that by calling the name property outright. I feel that is the culprit but don't have time to check for sure.

Comment: So, what would be the mechanism (if any) for getting at just the name by way of the variable? Split-Path doesn't work, because it interprets the / in the name as a separator, and just returns GENUINE.

Comment: I thought this seemed familiar https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49629753/split-path-with-non-standard-key-names have you just asked the same question again? I am assuming no good came from the comment thread there?

Comment: Does the property `PSChildName` get you what you want. I do not have that key structure available to do a  proper test. I think that is what is being used in your example above.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is this a bug? Intended behavior? Me doing something incorrectly?

The middle one.

PowerShell formatting files (*.format.ps1xml located in the directory defined in `$pshome` by default) explain the difference here. In a default output scenario PowerShell checks for known formatting definitions, which are loaded from aforementioned files, for given object types. If present, it will use those, which govern what data and how that data is outputted.

So, in your case, you have `Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey` objects. The format definitions for that are stored in registry.format.ps1xml. Just going to show a truncated section of that file so you can see how your top example is created.

```html
 .... output truncated ....
 <TableControl>
                <TableHeaders>
                   <TableColumnHeader>
                        <Width>30</Width>
                        <Label>Name</Label>
                    </TableColumnHeader>
                    <TableColumnHeader>
                      <Label>Property</Label>
                    </TableColumnHeader>
                </TableHeaders>
                <TableRowEntries>
                    <TableRowEntry>
                      <Wrap/>
                        <TableColumnItems>
                            <TableColumnItem>
                                <PropertyName>PSChildName</PropertyName>
.... output truncated ....
```

So this defines an output table with 2 columns: name, property. The name column is actually the objects pschildname property. This is separate from the actual name property of the object. This is why you get the difference you see above.

There are other examples of this misconception in the PS world as well. The more you know.

---

The go-to resource on formatting files would be [about_format.ps1xml](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_format.ps1xml?view=powershell-6). If you have issues with the default formatting and are not satisfied with simple `Select-Object` then you can create your own from copies.

---

FWIW you could have found both properties by just doing something like

```
Get-Item "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\MozillaPlugins\@microsoft.com/GENUINE" |  Format-List *
```

That would have forced *all* properties to show and you would have seen `name` and `pschildname`.

Comment: Where are these formatting files located? Can they be manually edited?

Comment: @djs `$pshome` is where you should be able to find it. e.g. C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0 have a read at [TechNet](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_format.ps1xml?view=powershell-6). I think you can edit them but you should make custom ones to superced them instead. Have to read more as I do not remember for sure.

Comment: @djs _The .ps1xml files that are installed with Windows PowerShell are digitally signed to prevent tampering because the formatting can include script blocks._ You can continue reading and it tells you how to make your own by copying existing ones.

Comment: Great! I commented partly because I was curious, but mostly because I think these details improve your answer! ;)

Comment: @djs I just came back to add them.